# how to access user information from facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Please give me some idea that how to access user's information through facebook application even though i have created one app which was registered in facebook which allow the users to add with that application so that we can access the user's information through the registered application.
Please reply me soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

check http://php-drops.blogspot.com/2011/04/facebook-login-fconnect-graph-api-php.html

Comment: Please do not post bare links with no explanation. Try to summarize the relevant part of the linked article(s) here to protect against link rot.

Answer (score 0):

That's going to depend on how much information you're looking to get about the user.  You can use the signed_request object to get the user that's signed in:

```
 list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
 $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);
```

And from the data get the user

```
$user = $data->user;
```

Once you have a verified and logged in user, you can use the graph API to get back what you want about the user as long as you've set up your permissions correctly:

```
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');  //  with $facebook being your authenticated FB object
```

The $user_profile will have all of the information about the user that's listed on this link:
[FB User Object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

Let me know if that's what you were asking about.  The above information is based on a PHP program, you can do most of that with the FBJS code as well.